# How can I import HTMLButtonElement into ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, native

I'd like use HTMLButtonElement instead React Button element in my code.
I get error when I run this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <button title="test" data-code="test" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Error message is:

> ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for
> component `button` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make
> sure to start component names with a capital letter.

Comment: You cannot use plain HTML in React Native.

Comment: Use `Button`, since you're in React Native.

Comment: You can use this library (`react-native-render-html `) to render HTML tag in React Native